# Find dates between values in array

Tags: jquery, date

I have an array with some dates in "dd/mm/yyyy" formatted as string.

```
var myDates = [ "01/04/2017", "11/12/2017", "12/09/2017", "02/03/2017" ];
```

1) How can I retrieve the dates between "01/02/2017" and "01/12/2017" only?

2) How can I convert a "dd/mm/yyyy" string to a date in the same format?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. And show some effort. You do not have 01/02/2017 ot 01/12/2017 in your array. It is also not clear if your array contains US or European dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter based on the required condition.

```js
var myDates = ["01/04/2017", "11/12/2017", "12/09/2017", "02/03/2017"];

var start = new Date(2017, 2, 1), // start date
  end = new Date(2017, 12, 1); // end date



var res = myDates.filter(function(date) {
  // parse the date
  var d = new Date(...date.split('/').reverse());
  // or for older browser which doesn't support ES6 spread syntax
  // var dA = date.split('/');
  // var d = new Date(dA[2], dA[1], dA[0]);  
  
  // check the date is in between start and end
  return d >= start && d <= end;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Pranav, the result should return "01/04/2017" and "02/03/2017" and it only returns  "01/04/2017".

Comment: @ElioFernandes :  what about `"12/09/2017"` ??

Comment: Sorry, that one too.

Comment: Thanks Pranav. :-)

Comment: @ElioFernandes : glad to help :)